# Can you provide quotes from scriptures which equate Lord Narayana with the Param Brahman or Supreme God?

Tags: vishnu

Please provide quotations with translation.

Comment: You are a great devotee of Narayana.?

Comment: The Vaishnavism school of thought believes this.

Comment: Questions should not be like demands. Please see [ask]

Comment: Some scriptures says Vishnu as supreme and some says Shiva as supreme. But the ultimate truth is both are same. None is above and none is below. Differentiating them is not wise act :)

Comment: @Sarvabhouma & TheDestroyer This Q is not a duplicate of the linked above. Sarvabhouma deleted the vaishnava tag, why? He wanted to ask about verses from the Vaishnava scriptures as well, and the linked answer above is only for Sruti!

Comment: @brahmajijnasa The tags Shaivism, Vaishnavism etc., should be used to ask question about the beliefs etc., of that sect only. They should not be used for questions about Vishnu or Shiva. Hence I removed it. See [About tags Vaishnavism and Shaivism](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/218/5212). There should be precise tagging. This is a duplicate as it is a canonical post. Having separate posts for Upanishads, Vedas, Puranas etc., is  not a good way for our site. Moreover, it is a list question which are discouraged on meta. We can edit that question to remove Vedas and make general.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Then make it general. Btw, the vaishnava tag may indicate he wanted a quotations of beliefs from the books of Vaishnava acaryas such as Ramanuja's, Gaudiyas, Madhvas, Nimbarkis, etc.